# Using complicated macro in \thanks command of abstract package

Tags: macros, two-column, expansion, abstract

The `\saythanks` command chokes when `\thanks` has been called with a macro that takes (and executes!) another macro as argument:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn,a5paper]{paper}
\usepackage{abstract}

\newcommand\thanksdefiner[1]{}
\newcommand\firstauthorthanks{\thanksdefiner{my thanks}}
\newcommand\extractthanks[1]{%
    \renewcommand\thanksdefiner[1]{##1}%
    #1
}

\title{Title}
\author{First Author \\Institution \thanks{\extractthanks\firstauthorthanks}}

\begin{document}
    \twocolumn[
        \maketitle
        % need full-width title
        \begin{onecolabstract}
            abstract text...
        \end{onecolabstract}
    ]
    \saythanks

    % works here:
    \extractthanks\firstauthorthanks
\end{document}
```

The sequence `\extractthanks\firstauthorthanks` expands to `my thanks`, and works when used within the document. Is there any way to call `\thanks` in this setting with a correct result? The definition of "thanks" for the first author

```
\newcommand\firstauthorthanks{\thanksdefiner{my thanks}}
```

is provided externally and should not be changed.

I have tried using `\DeclareExpandableDocumentCommand` to declare `\extractthanks`, without success. What kind of treatment would `\firstauthorthanks` require so that it can be passed safely as argument to `\thanks`?

Comment: The argument to `\thanks` is massaged with `\protected@xdef` and so the `\renewcommand` fails miserably. It's quite difficult to understand what you're trying to obtain.

Comment: @egreg: Right, if I define `\thanksdefiner` externally and do not change it in `\extractthanks`, it works. For my application, `\thanksdefiner` takes 7 arguments, which later have to be extracted from `\{first,second,third,...}authorthanks` macros. The `\newcommand\firstauthorthanks{\thanksdefiner{...}}` is a predefined idiom which I don't want to change.

Comment: After the explanation, I'm understanding less.

Comment: @egreg: `\firstauthorthanks` is supplied by the user in the `\thanksdefiner` syntax. Definition of `\author` is packaged and must read "thanks" information from `\firstauthorthanks`. That's the situation. I can't answer the "why?" question that I feel coming, because I inherited this setup. Also, I'm willing to keep things that way, because there's a fairly large user base with quite a lot of existing documents that rely on this syntax.

Comment: @egreg: To put it in another way: In the example above, only the line `\newcommand\firstauthorthanks{\thanksdefiner{my thanks}}` is supplied by the user. Everything else I can change.

Comment: Why should it be like this and not `\firstauthorthanks{my thanks}`, which is a proper user level command?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/10984/discussion-between-krlmlr-and-egreg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Avoiding the use of `\renewcommand` inside `\extractthanks` solves the issue, at least for me:

```
\newcommand\thanksdefiner[1]{#1}%
\newcommand\firstauthorthanks{\thanksdefiner{my thanks}}
\newcommand\extractthanks[1]{%
    #1
}
```

Also, adding the necessary amount of `\protect`ion solves the issue, too (don't need to change first part in this case):

```
\author{First Author \\Institution
       \thanks{\protect\extractthanks{\protect\firstauthorthanks}}}
```

I still don't know enough about `\protected@xdef` to be able to explain any of this. It's just observed behavior...

Comment: As I said, the argument to `\thanks` is massaged by `\protected@xdef`; since `\renewcommand` makes assignments it fails there, but defining `\thanksdefiner` essentially as a no-op in advance doesn't suffer from this problem. It remains a mystery *why* `\thanksdefiner` should appear in the first place.